# Using XCTest with Objective-C++ code: "Unexpected @ in program" errors

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, objective-c++, xctest

I've inherited a project which contains a lot of Objective-C++ code, and no unit tests. I'm attempting to set up testing, using Xcode 6.1.1 and XCTest.   I've started by creating a new Cocoa Touch unit testing bundle with default settings.

When I create a standard `XCTest` subclass, everything works fine. When I then include an Obj-C++ file, the build stage breaks with various C++-related errors.  That's understandable, because the test subclass needs to be compiled as an Obj-C++ class.

When I switch the `XCTest` subclass from `myTests.m` to `myTests.mm`, the build stage breaks again, but this time with

`Unexpected '@' in program`

There are two additional errors being shown :

`Expanded from macro 'XCTAssert'`

`Expanded from macro '_XCTPrimitiveAssertTrue'`

The errors are being caused by the NSString parameter of the XCAssert call - replacing this with a standard C string in the test case doesn't fix the problem.

If I switch the C++ standard library for the test target from `libstdc++` to `libc++` the `@` errors disappear, but then the compilation of the Obj-C++ code in the rest of the project fails.

I don't know enough about Obj-C++ to figure this one out - are there some additional compiler flags I need to set in order to use `XCTest` successfully?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? I just created a new project in Xcode 6.1.1 and changed an XCTest subclass to use `.mm` as the file extension. It’s compiling as Objective-C++ just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you quite sure the error is being caused by the NSString you're passing? You can test that assumption by passing nil, or by putting the string into a variable and passing the variable. The reason I ask is that _XCTPrimitiveAssertTrue contains several @-prefixed keywords, and it seems conceivable that one of those could be tripping things up (though I don't know why).

Also it might be enlightening to see the verbatim compiler invocation and output (or not. I'm not making any promises here).

Comment: Thanks - I've tried various combinations of passing nil and strings into the XCTAssert call, and they're all failing - the detail in the log is:

`Unexpected @ in program`
`Expanded from macro XCTAssert`
`Expanded from macro _XCTPrimitiveAssertTrue`